# Problem accessing members of same parented structures in a vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, struct

I put some different structs that inherits from the same parent struct but when I try to access their members, compiler gives me an error. The code is this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a=0;
};

struct B:A
{
    int b=0;
};

struct C:A
{
    int c=0;
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> va;
    B bb;
    C cc;
    va.push_back(bb);
    va.push_back(cc);
    cout<<va[0].b;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is this:

```
'__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<A> >::value_type {aka struct A}' has no member named 'b'|
```

What could I do to solve this???

Comment: You're slicing the `bb` and `cc` to just the `A` part.  Polymorphism and inheritance necessitate the use of pointers and references.  Try a `vector<unique_ptr<A>>` instead.

Comment: Obligatory link to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: *What could I do to solve this???* -- I have to ask -- are you a Java or C# programmer trying to learn C++?  In Java, you can do things like this, but not in C++.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you, I will investigate about that unique_ptr

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well I was a Competitive Programmer 2 years ago when I was in pre-universitary school (I think you call it high school) and all I used for competitions was C++. But then I moved to Unity and learned C# to try some game development. Now Im back in C++ learning just for fun, maybe I keep a few C# habits jaja.